# "Remove" in else clause changes results of loop over json dict

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am iterating over a dict created from a json file which works fine but as soon as I remove some of the entries in the `else` clause the results change (normally it prints 35 nuts_ids but with the `remove` in the `else` only 32 are printed. So it seems that the remove influences the iterating but why? The key should be safe? How can I do this appropriately without loosing data?

```
import json

with open("test.json") as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)

for g in json_data["features"]:
    poly = g["geometry"]
    cntr_code = g["properties"]["CNTR_CODE"]
    nuts_id = g["properties"]["NUTS_ID"]
    name = g["properties"]["NUTS_NAME"]
    if cntr_code == "AT":
        print(nuts_id)
        # do plotting etc
    else: # delete it if it is not part a specific country
        json_data["features"].remove(g)  # line in question

# do something else with the json_data
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a good practice to delete items while iterating the object. Instead you can try filtering out the elements you do need.

**Ex:**

```
import json

with open("test.json") as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)

json_data_features = [g for g in json_data["features"] if g["properties"]["CNTR_CODE"] == "AT"]  #Filter other country codes.  
json_data["features"] = json_data_features

for g in json_data["features"]:
    poly = g["geometry"]
    cntr_code = g["properties"]["CNTR_CODE"]
    nuts_id = g["properties"]["NUTS_ID"]
    name = g["properties"]["NUTS_NAME"]
    # do plotting etc

# do something else with the json_data
```

Answer (score 1):

Always remember the cardinal rule, **never modify objects you are iterating on**

You can take a copy of your dictionary and then iterate on it using `copy.copy`

```
import json
import copy
with open("test.json") as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)

#Take copy of json_data 
json_data_copy = json_data['features'].copy()

#Iterate on the copy
for g in json_data_copy:
    poly = g["geometry"]
    cntr_code = g["properties"]["CNTR_CODE"]
    nuts_id = g["properties"]["NUTS_ID"]
    name = g["properties"]["NUTS_NAME"]
    if cntr_code == "AT":
        print(nuts_id)
        # do plotting etc
    else: # delete it if it is not part a specific country
        json_data["features"].remove(g)  # line in question
```

Comment: It is clear to me that I can not modify a list while iterating but why not a dict? Is there a way without copy in order to avoid double memory useage?

Comment: Any object will have the same problem, be a dict or a list! @lordy

Comment: But the key points to a specific location that should dynamically change?